# Rank and Rank Increment/Decrement from selected week vs previous week

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visual with branch, client and revenue information. The revenue is coming from a measure which is affected by the week selector slicer.
[image]

I need to show Rank for selected week and rank increment/decrement from selected week's rank vs previous week from selected week. In snapshot, Rank # and Rank are the requirements.

I tried to create rank with AllSelected function but it is always affected by week slicer and I cannot get previous week rank to compare and put Rank increment/decrement.
DAX I tried for Rank

```
  This Week GP = 

var _Total = 
    CALCULATE(
            SUM(V_TopClients[revenue]),
           DATESBETWEEN('Date'[date],[current_week_start_date], [current_week_end_date])
        
    )

    return _Total


Previous Week GP = 

var _Total = 
    CALCULATE(
            SUM(V_TopClients[revenue]),
           DATESBETWEEN('Date'[date],[previous_week_start_date], [previous_week_end_date])
        
    )

    return _Total

Rank This Week = 
    RANKX(
                ALLSELECTED(V_TopClients),
                CALCULATE(SUM(V_TopClients[Revenue])
                )
            )
```

--Update: added dax for measures

Here I am able to get the rank for this week i.e. the week selected on slicer.
But unable to get rank for previous week.

I have v_TopClients that has weekly revenue information linking to dimCalendar, Date tables.

Comment: Are you showing weekly branch wise top client?

Comment: @mkRabbani Yep, data shown weekly ( based on week slicer ) for branch wise Top Clients i.e. top clients based on Revenue.

Comment: What branch wise top clients means? you are keeping the 1 single client for each branch based on revenue?

Comment: Basically my report shows top 100 clients based on their revenue for the selected week. 
The branch is just another additional information on the table visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another and probably the best option for you-

**Step-1:**
Create a new custom table based on your table "TopClient". The code is as below-

```
group_by_result_new = 
VAR group_wise_revenue = 
GROUPBY (  
    TopClients,
    TopClients[CalendarWeekKey],
    TopClients[clientID],
    "gp_this_week", SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(), TopClients[GrossProfit])
) 

RETURN
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    group_wise_revenue,
    "CalendarWeekKey", TopClients[CalendarWeekKey],
    "clientID", TopClients[clientID],
    "gp_this_week", [gp_this_week]
)
```

**Step-2:**
Create relation between table "DimCalendar" and "group_by_result_new" using the column "CalendarWeekKey"

**Step-3:**
Create a new column (**remember it a column**) as below-

```
gp_prev_week = 
VAR client_id = group_by_result_new[clientID]
VAR calendar_key_this_week = group_by_result_new[CalendarWeekKey]

VAR end_date_this_week = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    DimCalendar[WeekEndingDate],
    DimCalendar[CalendarWeekKey], CONVERT(calendar_key_this_week,INTEGER)
)

VAR end_date_prev_week = CONVERT(end_date_this_week,DATETIME) - 7 

VAR calendar_key_prev_week =
LOOKUPVALUE(
    DimCalendar[CalendarWeekKey],
    DimCalendar[WeekEndingDate] , end_date_prev_week
)

VAR gp_prev_week = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    group_by_result_new[gp_this_week],
    group_by_result_new[CalendarWeekKey],calendar_key_prev_week,
    group_by_result_new[clientID], CONVERT(client_id,INTEGER)
)

RETURN gp_prev_week
```

**Step-4:**
Create a new column (**remember it a column**) for RANK this week as below-

```
rank_this_week = 
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        group_by_result_new,
        group_by_result_new[CalendarWeekKey] = EARLIER (group_by_result_new[CalendarWeekKey])
    ),
    group_by_result_new[gp_this_week],
    ,
    DESC
    // ,
    // DENSE
)
```

**Step-5:**
Create a new column (**remember it a column**) for RANK prev week as below-

```
rank_prev_week = 
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        group_by_result_new,
        group_by_result_new[CalendarWeekKey] = EARLIER (group_by_result_new[CalendarWeekKey])
    ),
    group_by_result_new[gp_prev_week],
    ,
    DESC
    // ,
    // DENSE
)
```

And that's all! This should also work same as my previous solution.
Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks @mKRabbani. This works in import method but I am using direct query method. Your solution game some ideas for me. Thanks for investing your time on this.

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan not sure what issue you are facing. But I am getting exact same output with direct query.

Comment: You can check report downloaded from here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/11x23cYbku0-PuJN5xY82e_7LFzuw1SfK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Once a custom table is added, the storage mode goes to mixed-mode, I need pure directquery method for storage. ?And look up value function cannot be applied on direct query method

Comment: can you provide me the sample report file with data loading (using direct query) done with sample data?

Comment: Can you please check our chat?

Answer (score 1):

In DAX, there are builtin function PREVIOUSMONTH, PREVIOUSQUARTER and PREVIOUSYEAR available. But as you are searching for weekly data comparison, you required your own date periods to calculate. I just can give you some idea as below-

First, crate 4 measure based on your slicer week/date selection.

Example:

```
current_week_end_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[Date])
current_week_start_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[Date]) - 7

previous_week_end_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[Date]) - 8
previous_week_start_date = SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[Date]) - 15
```

Now, you need 2 separate measure to calculate this week and previous week total revenue. Example Measures are given below-

**1.**

```
this_week_revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(table[revenue]),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        'Dates'[Date],
        [current_week_start_date],
        [current_week_end_date]
    )
)
```

**2.**

```
previous_week_revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(table[revenue]),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        'Dates'[Date],
        [previous_week_start_date],
        [previous_week_end_date]
    )
)
```

Now you have both weekly value in your hand and you can compare measure "this_week_revenue " with measure "previous_week_revenue" to generate the directions indicators.

Hope this will help!

**Below image is just for reference:**

[image: Just for ref:]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to get this week and last week revenue. I need to show the indicators based on ranking of this week and last week for the clients. I have a week selector on report and am able to get rank for current week using all selected. Do you mind providing your input how to calculate rank for previous week?

Comment: Can you add 3 measure in your question? 1. This week calculation 2. last week calculation and 3) rank on this week data.

Comment: I have added the calculations for this week , last week and rank for this week on my original question, Due to the week slicer on my report, I am unable to get rank for previous week.

Comment: I will check more.

Comment: If it would be easier, Please find the sample data here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ave_-9o8DQVEgRq42F7E2tvw1s9_?e=0CRLM4

Comment: Using your sample data, I have reached some output and added the output for your ref bottom of my answer. Please check @SuccessMaharjan

Comment: Yes, I wanted to get something like that rank_prev_week. Could you please let me know how you got that? My requirement is to show this week rank vs previous week rank in an indicator on the table visual.

Comment: i did a lot of thing with your sample data. Its better if i can share the full pbix file with you. Can you wait till tomorrow as i closed my work station and replying you from my mobile now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218467/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-success-maharjan).